# Teradata group by time interval

Tags: sql, teradata, group-by

Can anyonen help with Teradata?

I want to create a query that is a standard

select count(*) 
from Table 
where Column = Something

but has a group by time period  done by 5 minute time intervals the time column is in 'Time' format

any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT HOUR(timecolumn) AS h, MINUTE(timecolumn)-(MINUTE(timecolumn) MOD 5) AS m, COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE column=something
GROUP BY h, m
```

(SQL:2003's `FLOOR` is a common way to do periodic grouping, but I believe Teradata doesn't support it, hence the `n-(n MOD m)` construct.)